# Ctrl-Alt-F1 to F6 work differently for left and right sides of the keyboard

Tags: linux, keyboard, console

If I want to log in to the traditional text shell, I can only use the right side control and alt keys, the left side ones will do nothing.  Once I switch to another shell, I now have to use the *left* ctrl and alt keys if I want to switch back to the graphical shell (or a different text shell).

I'm using Fedora 16.  What gives?

Comment: Did you mean one of those to be left?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a keyboard mapping where one of the keys labeled `Alt` does not actually act as the `Alt` modifier.  For instance, some layouts will map the right-Alt key to `AltGr` instead.

To find out what is happening, try running the `xev` program in your X session.  It will display all of the keyboard events that it receives.

Comment: I'm getting Alt_R and Alt_L, as well as Ctrl_R and Ctrl_L.  So they definitely are distinguishing between left and right for some reason.

Comment: @davidglanzman That's normal, so it's not the cause of your problem.